# I want know how pointer p is getting assigned to the address of str

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char *p;
    char str[10],name_first[10];
    int i,count;

    printf("\nName before reversing the string:::::::::::::");
    scanf("%s",&name_first);

    // I have taken a name in name_variable and now i want to reverse it
    // using pointer for ex
    count = strlen(name_first);

    p=str+strlen(name_first)-1;

    for(i=0;i<count;i++)
    {
        *(p-i)=*(name_first+i);
    }

    // now I am getting a reverse of string as a o/p but I want to know
    // how p is pointing to the str as I'm not assigning any address,
    // is it done automatically by the compiler?
    printf("\nname after reversing the string::::::::::::::%s\n",str);
}
```

Comment: `p=str+strlen(name_first)-1;` this line assign address of `str`, offset by `strlen ...`  etc. amount of `sizeof(char)` to `p`

Answer (score 1):

Actually you are assigning address to `p` in the following line of code.

```
p=str+strlen(name_first)-1;
```

`str` is an array so array name keeps the base address. Now adding the length of `name_first` array and subtracting `1` does the pointer arithmetic hence you are getting the result.

You have created a variable `count = strlen(name_first)`.

So no need to call `strlen` again to assign the address to `p`.

For faster way , Just use

`p=str+count-1;`

Comment: @pravinkumar : If you satisfied with the answer , you can upvote and accept the answer

Answer (score 1):

The statement:

```
p=str+strlen(name_first)-1;
```

assigns to p an address within the memory pointed to by str.

So, let's say str starts at address 0x1000 and has a length of 10 and your name_first has a length of 5. Then p points to 0x1004.

When you loop runs, you are updating the characters in 0x1004, 0x1003, 0x1002, 0x1001 and 0x1000, thereby updating the contents of str.

Hope this clears your doubt.

Answer (score 0):

str is the pointer of the first element of str[10]. In this statement: "p=str+strlen(name_first)-1;"  rhs is an address

Answer (score 0):

p, the pointer to a char, is assigned the address of the last char in the char array str in your p= line.

You then proceed to use that pointer to manipulate chars in that block of memory and them print out the manipulate memory content (because str is really just a pointer to the char array anyway).